Logging in with swift using linkedin api/creds
Hey All Junior Developer here!
I am trying to implement a login script that uses Linkedin API in my app (log in using linkedin credentials).
I have a hard time with OpenID Connect
When I run my app this is the error I get in the url:

url Foundation.URL    "https://loginsample152.com/auth/linkedin/callback?error=invalid_scope_error&error_description=Unknown+scope+%26quot%3Br_liteprofile%2520r_emailaddress%2520w_member_social%2520openid%26quot%3B&state=xyz123"

this is where the error occurs:
if url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("redirect_uri") {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                // Handle the URL and extract authorization code
                if let code = extractCode(from: url) {
                    print("Authorization code: \(code)")
                    // Potentially exchange code for token here
                }
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        }

This is the script so far:
import SwiftUI

struct LogInView: View {
    
    var authorizationUrl: URL {
        
        let scopes = "r_liteprofile r_emailaddress w_member_social openid" // Correct space-separated scopes
        let encodedScopes = scopes.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""

        
        var components = URLComponents(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization")!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "response_type", value: "code"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "client_id", value: "client_id"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "redirect_uri", value: "redirect_uri"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "scope", value: encodedScopes),
            URLQueryItem(name: "state", value: "random_state")  // Example state value
        ]
        return components.url!
    }

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // Using the WebView
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: authorizationUrl))
    }
}

}
I suspect that the invalid scopes error I have has to do with the openId but on www.linkedin.com/developers I cannot find instructions Sign In with LinkedIn and I have no idea how to handle the OpenID Connect. Anyone else has done this before?
I mean having log in with Linkedin on a mobile ios app using swiftui(xcode)

If you print the output or run it in a playground, you can see the scope gets double-encoded:
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&scope=r_liteprofile%2520r_emailaddress%2520w_member_social%2520openid&state=random_state
                                                                                                                                    ^^^^^              ^^^^^               ^^^^^

You need to either use scopes instead of encodedScopes or set percentEncodedQueryItems instead of queryItems.
